# Mapping over an array to render images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I am trying to create cards that display an image with a description. I have an array with the data for each card. The cards are appearing with the description, but the images aren't rendering.

The Card Component:

```
export const Card = (props) => (
  <div className="card">
    <a href={props.href} target="_blank">
      <img className="card-image" src={props.src} alt={props.alt} />
      <h3 className="card-title">{props.title}</h3>
      <p className="card-description">{props.description}</p>
    </a>
  </div>
);
```

A Callback Function and the Projects component that maps through the array:

```
const renderCard = (project) => (
  <Card
    href={project.href}
    src={project.src}
    alt={project.alt}
    title={project.title}
    description={project.description}
    key={project.id}
  />
);

const Projects = () => {
  const cardElements = projects.map(renderCard);
  return (
    <div id="projects-section">
      <h1 className="title">Projects</h1>
      {cardElements}
    </div>
  );
};
```

And the data is coming from this projects array:

```
import retreat from "../images/retreat.jpg";
import guess from "../images/guessTheWord.jpg";
import jsKeyboard from "../images/drum-kit.jpg";
import ptWebsite from "../images/ptWebsite.jpg";
import stickyNotes from "../images/sticky-notes-app.jpg";
import firstWebsite from "../images/my-first-website.jpg";

export const projects = [
  {
    href: "https://patgramo.github.io/unplugged-retreat/",
    src: { retreat },
    alt: "Card image",
    title: "Company Retreat Website",
    description:
      "I created a website for a company retreat to practice using media queries with CSS. This was a project through Skillcrush.",
    id: "01"
  },
  {
    href: "https://patgramo.github.io/guess-the-word/",
    src: { guess },
    alt: "Card image",
    title: "Guess The Word Game",
    description:
      "Here I created a guess-the-word game using my JavaScript and CSS knowledge. This was the final project in Skillcrush's JavaScript course.",
    id: "02"
  }
];
```

Comment: `src` isn't a String in your data structure, its an object.

Answer (score 2):

The values you're setting for `src` are objects, not strings. On your first entry `src` is an object with a `retreat` property. Remove the curlies.

```json
{
    href: "https://patgramo.github.io/unplugged-retreat/",
    src: retreat,
    alt: "Card image",
    title: "Company Retreat Website",
    description:
      "I created a website for a company retreat to practice using media queries with CSS. This was a project through Skillcrush.",
    id: "01"
},
```